# How to add whichever character between every character of a premade String?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

How to add whichever character between every character of a premade String? (JAVA)

For example, I have the String "Hello world" and I have to add '_' between every character of the String.

Any function or useful code I can use to do it?

I have to do an algorithm that make me output "H_e_l_l_o_ _w_o_r_l_d"

This is what I have:

```
public String example(String s) {
        String s2 = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            s2 += s.charAt(i) + (((i+1) == 0) ? " " : "-");     
            }
        return s2;
     }
```

My output in the main class is being:

nullH-e-l-l-o- -w-o-r-l-d-

Don't know why

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  In order to help you with your problem, please post a minimum, complete example, and then ask which part you are having trouble with. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: public String example(String s) {
  String s2 = null;
  for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
   s2 += s.charAt(i) + (((i+1) == 0) ? " " : "-");  
   }
  return s2;
 }

Comment: So the obvious solution is don't start with null: `String s2 = null;`.  Instead start with a non-null empty String `String s2 = "";`

Comment: Closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I realized it out. This was my first message in Stack Overflow, didn't know people will answer so fast.

Comment: package temp;

public class Temp {
 
 
 public  String strReplace(String s) { 
   String s2="";
   StringBuilder s3=null;
  for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){ 
   s2= s2+s.charAt(i) + (((i+1) == 0) ? " " : "-");
  }
  s3 = new StringBuilder(s2);
  s3.deleteCharAt(s3.length()-1);
  return s3.toString(); 
  }

 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Temp t = new Temp();
   String s1 = t.strReplace("helloworld");
   System.out.println(s1);
  
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework assignment. So, I won't directly write out all the code.

`String = "hello world"`;

Say, there is a variable `len = str.length() - 1`. Instead of doing it from index `0`, we will start our for loop from `len - 1`. The character `'d'` is at index `len`, and the `'_'` will have to be inserted right before that. This can be done by setting the string to `str = str.substring(0,i) + "_" + str.substring(i+1);`

You will have to use a for loop that starts from `len - 1` and goes on till the index reached is `0`.

Now, on every single iteration, when you are inserting a character assigning str to `str.substring(0,i) + "_" + str.substring(i+1);` causes you to make a new string object, which is absolutely horrible style. This can be solved by using a `StringBuilder`.

Does that make it clear?

**In the future, refrain from posting questions without having done any work. This community is there to help you with solving issues that you may have in your solutions, not write your solutions for you.**